# MassTransit How to avoid creating an unneeded exchange

Tags: c#, masstransit

I use Net 6 API application which publishes and consumes messages via MassTransit using RabbitMQ as transport. I would like define a messages hierarchy with a common ancestor to all messages to centralize the common data shared by all the messages. Something like:

```
public abstract class IntegrationEvent
{
    public string Code { get; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; }

    public IntegrationEvent(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
        DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class Event1 : IntegrationEvent
{
    public string DataEvent1 { get; set; } = "";

    Event1(string dataEvent1) : base("Event1")
    {
        DataEvent1 = dataEvent1;
    }
}

public class Event2 : IntegrationEvent
{
    public string DataEvent2 { get; set; } = "";

    Event2(string dataEvent2) : base("Event2")
    {
        DataEvent2 = dataEvent2;
    }
}
```

I only want to publish messages from Event1 and Event2 types, but I have to configure the message for `IntegrationEvent` when I configure the messages' topology to avoid creating an `IntegrationEvent` exchange in RabbitMQ. Commenting out the first `configurator.Message<>` makes the exchange.

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureMessageTopology(this IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        // Primary exchanges names.
        configurator.Message<IntegrationEvent>(x => x.SetEntityName("service.publisher"));
        configurator.Message<Event1>(x => x.SetEntityName("service.publisher"));
        configurator.Message<Event2>(x => x.SetEntityName("service.publisher"));
```

Is there some way to avoid this?

I've tried to find some function in `IMessageTopologyConfigurator` to avoid defining an exchange for a message without luck.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ExcludeFromTopology`](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/topology/message#excludefromtopology) attribute can be used, which is described in the linked documentation. You can also configure the publish topology as shown in the documentation as well.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm... I've been reading the online documentation and I didn't find that point, my fault