# MassTransit How to implement a sniffer

Tags: c#, masstransit

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244117/masstransit-how-to-avoid-creating-an-unneeded-exchange), I have the same messages hierarchy and I would like implement one consumer which can handle all the different messages, to implement a kind of sniffer.

I've though in something like

```
public class Sniffer : IConsumer<IntegrationEvent>
{
    readonly ILogger<Sniffer> _logger;

    public Sniffer(ILogger<Sniffer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IntegrationEvent> context)
    {
        IntegrationEvent data = context.Message;

        _logger.LogInformation($"EVENT: ***{data.Code} - {data.DateTime}***");

        if (code == "Event1")
        {
            DataEvent1 dataEvent1 = ??????
            _logger.LogInformation($"EVENT1: ***{dataEvent1.DataEvent1}***");
        }
        else if (code == "Event2")
        {
            DataEvent2 dataEvent2 = ??????
            _logger.LogInformation($"EVENT2: ***{dataEvent2.DataEvent2}***");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can get a DataEvent1 or DataEvent2 object from the context.Message? Maybe I need to use a different serializer/deserializer instead of the default one?

I've tried the previous code but the serialized object that I get in the consumer is only an IntegrationEvent one, and no casting can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages#classes) points it seems it's not a good idea what I'm trying to do:

> A common mistake when engineers are new to messaging is to create a base class for messages, and try to dispatch that base class in the consumer – including the behavior of the subclass. Ouch. This always leads to pain and suffering, so just say no to base classes.